# How I can make "alias" database states using other states on Laravel Factories?

Tags: php, laravel

In my project I have a `Car` model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use App\Model\Driver

class Car extends Model
{
  protected $table='car'

  function driver(): HasOne
  {
    return $this->hasOne(Driver::class);
  }
}
```

The equivalent database table is:

```
class Car
--------------
id: Primary Key
status: VARCHAR(20)
drivable: BOOLEAN
driver_id: FK Driver
```

For the `Driver` The model is:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use App\Model\Car

class Driver extends Model
{
  protected $table='driver'

  function cats(): HasOne
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
  }
}
```

That represents the following table:

```
Driver:
----
Id: Primary Key
namae: VARCHAR(40)
```

And I for this model I want to have the following factories:

```
use App\Model\Car;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Car::class,function(Faker $faker){
  return [
    'drivable'=> $faker->boolean(),
    'status' => $faker->asciify('test_***');
  ];
});


$factory->states(Car::class,'in_drift_mode',['drivable'=true,'status'=>'in_drift']);
```

Also for my `Driver` I have the following factories as well:

```
use App\Model\Driver;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Driver::class,function(Faker $faker){
  return [
    'namae'=>$faker->name()
  ];
});

$factory->define(Driver::class,'keitshi_tsutsiya',['name'=>'Keitshi Tsutsiya']);
$factory->define(Driver::class,'ken_block',['name'=>'Ken BLock']);
```

And I want to make an alias state `keichi_tsutsuya_drives_it` that will generate an `in_drift_mode` Car with a driver having name `Keitchi Tsutsiya`. Also a car that `Ken Block` drives is in drift mode hence I cannot just add an `afterCreatingState` and hardcoding a `Driver`.

So how I can create an alias state `keichi_tsutsiya_drives_it` that will "extends" the `in_drift_mode` state?